# Stop timer after disconnect call in twilio php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twilio

I am working with call connect and disconnect module in php using twilio api,Whenever i disconnect then timer not stop, Here is my code

//timer start when click on answer button

```
$('#answer').on('click', function() {

var countdown = document.getElementsByTagName('countdown')[0],
    start = document.getElementById('start'),
    stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
    clear = document.getElementById('clear'),
    seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
    t;

function add() {
    seconds++;
    if (seconds >= 60) {
        seconds = 0;
        minutes++;
        if (minutes >= 60) {
            minutes = 0;
            hours++;
        }
    }
countdown.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);

document.getElementById('checkyear').value = countdown.textContent;
    timer();
}
function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
timer();
 });
```

//Timer should stop when disconnect the call

```
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function (conn) {
    clearTimeout(t);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think the issue here is one of scope. Your variable `t`, which is set to the ID of the timeouts you are using to count time up, is only available within the event handling function that is called when you click on the answer button.

When it's inside the `Twilio.Device.disconnect` handler, `t` is `undefined`.

I would rearrange your code so that the timing variables and functions are outside of the click event handler, so they are in scope for the `disconnect` handler. Something like this:

```
var t, seconds, minutes, hours;

Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(conn) {
  clearTimeout(t);
});

function add() {
  seconds++;
  if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
      minutes = 0;
      hours++;
    }
  }
  countdown.textContent =
    (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : '0' + hours) : '00') +
    ':' +
    (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes) : '00') +
    ':' +
    (seconds > 9 ? seconds : '0' + seconds);

  document.getElementById('checkyear').value = countdown.textContent;
  timer();
}

function timer() {
  t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}

$('#answer').on('click', function() {
  var countdown = document.getElementsByTagName('countdown')[0],
      start = document.getElementById('start'),
      stop = document.getElementById('stop'),
      clear = document.getElementById('clear');

  seconds = 0;
  minutes = 0;
  hours = 0;
  timer();
});
```